# Android: Set minDinstance between two views while there is a view between them

Tags: android, android-layout

I got this layout in my app:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/item_list_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:minWidth="35dp"
        android:minHeight="35dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_garbage"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/basket_item_list_delete"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/basket_item_list_delete"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/basket_item_list_increment"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/basket_item_list_increment"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_itemname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="ItemName"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:text="Options"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_increment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/basket_item_list_count"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/basket_item_list_count"
        android:minWidth="35dp"
        android:minHeight="35dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/generalText"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/basket_item_list_decrement"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/basket_item_list_decrement"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="nx"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_decrement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/basket_item_list_price"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/basket_item_list_price"
        android:minWidth="35dp"
        android:minHeight="35dp"
        android:text="–"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/generalText"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="1€"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now my Problem is, that the textfield between the plus and the minus button is dynamically set. So sometimes it is empty and sometimes there is content in it. Same goes for the price on the right side. Sometimes it is a longer string sometimes shorter. Now because of this the buttons get moved as you can see in this picture:

[image]

I would like to prevent this by setting a bigger minDistance between these two buttons from the beginning. And the same for the right button and the right screen end. But I got no clue how to do this.

Comment: You could set a fixed width for you textview (both counter and price). So it never change. And for the counter when there isn't just put no text inside but let the textview

Comment: @vincrichaud When doing this the text will be on the left side. Do you know how the price text will still stand on the right side of the bigger textview?

Comment: If I remember well, there is textAlign property in textview wher you can force the text to be align on the right

Comment: this is a perfect case scenario for using ContraintLayout and the guidelines https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `android:minWidth=""` option on your textView

Comment: This in combination with setting gravity to right fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a fixed width for textview instead of seting wrap_content as follows

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/basket_item_list_count"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/basket_item_list_decrement"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/basket_item_list_decrement"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="nx"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

Comment: Try it, and ping me